# MySQL - Select from with not in statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I has very strange situation with MySQL.
I have 2 tables. 
First table has column ID (primary key) and has ~560 000 rows.
Second table has column IDBook (rows from first table from ID column) and has ~259 000 rows.

If I try to try search from first table

```
SELECT * FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.book
where id=66764
```

then one row returned.

If I try to try search from second table

```
SELECT * FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.autors
where IDBook=66764
```

then 0 rows returned.

It's OK.

But. If I execute SQL script

```
SELECT count(b1.id) FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.book b1
where b1.id not in (
select IDBook 
from `testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig`.`autors`

)
```

then returned 0.

Why?

Comment: What happens if you remove the apices? testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.autors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `IDBook` column have `null` values?

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(b1.id) 
FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.book b1
WHERE b1.id NOT IN (
  SELECT IDBook 
  FROM `testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig`.`autors`
  WHERE IDBook IS NOT NULL 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually cause by `NULL` values in `autors.IDBook`.  You can fix it in two easy ways.  The first is:

```
SELECT count(b1.id)
FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.book b1
WHERE b1.id not in (select a.IDBook 
                    from `testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig`.`autors` a
                    where a.IDBook is not NULL
                   );
```

The second is to use `NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT count(b1.id)
FROM testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig.book b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select a.IDBook 
                  from `testovoe_zadanie_poisk_knig`.`autors` a
                  where b1.id = a.IDBook
                 );
```

The semantics of `NOT IN` with `NULL` values is a bit counter-intuitive.  If any of the values in the subquery are `NULL`, then the query says "I don't know if a given value is in the list.".  So, it returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.  This is ANSI standard behavior, and not specific to MySQL.

The `NOT EXISTS` form has the semantics you expect.  If a value is `NULL` in the subquery, then it is ignored.  For this reason, I (and others) usually recommend `NOT IN` for this type of comparison.